# How to run only failed tests (protractor+jasmine)

Tags: automation, jasmine, protractor

We have ~150 e2e tests and executing in multiple browsers like chrome, firefox, IE, Edge & Safari. Few tests are failing on different reasons. Is it possible to execute only failed tests using protractor?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use `protractor-flake` => https://www.npmjs.com/package/protractor-flake

It's able to rerun whole spec files. You actually can provide a parser which receives all test output. We use this and it's very helpful.